# Firewalld kills iptables

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, firewalld

I have centos7 with  installed firewalld and fail2ban.
When i'm start firewalld(service firewalld start) it kills iptables (and starting iptables kills runing firewalld).
Can i remove iptables and use only firewalld? 
Fail2ban action firewallcmd-ipset/allports/multiport use iptables to block.
Could someone explain right way to setup firewalld+fail2ban ?

Comment: You can remove the service for `iptables`. Since `firewalld` is a higher level configuration tool for `iptables`, those services will conflict each other. You might also want to look at [Fail2ban with FireallD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fail2ban_with_FirewallD).

Comment: And how block ip with firewalld ?
`firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="ip" reject'` not working :(

Comment: `firewalld` relies on zones. You have to apply the rules to zones. Default zone should be public. You also might want to start reading the [documention](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.zones.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not start the old `iptables` service if you intend to use `firewalld`. Start only `firewalld` and remove the other service.

The scripts comprising the old `iptables` service are in the RPM package named `iptables-services`, so you can remove this package from your system, and afterward use only firewalld.

```
yum remove iptables-services
```

(But do not remove the RPM package named `iptables`. You still need this as it contains the `iptables` command line tool.)

I recommend you set your fail2ban `banaction` to `firewallcmd-ipset`, as this gives the highest performance with very large lists of IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry for dummy question, firewallcmd-ipset not baning, in fail2ban.log are 
`fail2ban.actions        [15485]: NOTICE  [name] Ban myip
   fail2ban.filter         [15485]: INFO    [name] Found  myip
   fail2ban.filter         [15485]: INFO    [name] Found myip` And not banning. What  i do wrong ?